# can i make poster from my phd thesis?

Tags: publications, thesis, conference

I finished my phd on 2017 , nearly a year and half. Since then, i have not had chance to do any project research for some circumstances. As my job asked me to apply for poster or presentation in a conference, due to career obligation, i have thought to do poster from my phd thesis, my question is that possible to do ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Why do you have doubts?

Comment: First of all thank you for answering. I dunno but i though since it was published in university library. it would have been hard do any thing from it. Anyway thank you for your answering.

Comment: If you elaborate on _since it was published in university library[,] it would have been hard do any thing from it_, then I'll try to elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.  [Colin Purrington](https://colinpurrington.com/tips/poster-design) has some extremely good advice on how to go about it.  There are even templates you can use.

Edit: You've added that your thesis was published in a university library. That's OK.  It is your work, so you are allowed to present it in a different form.  Your poster is going to summarize the problem you tackled and showcase the relevant results. You shouldn't try to present the entire thesis as a poster; only the very most important parts..

Comment: Thank you so much , it's helpful